# How to re-arrange the order of saved objects in Django database

Tags: jquery, python, django, database, sqlite

I am using jQuery UI Sortable to allow users to sort images that they have uploaded by drag & drop. Here's how it works:

when they upload some pictures, they are directed to another page in which all the newly uploaded images are displayed in a column on the left. Users can drop photos from the left column to the right column in the order they wish. I'm using jQuery Serialize to get the sorted array.

My question is, how can I update my database to re-arrange the images and save the order same as the one returned by Serialize?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't alter the order in your database, have your database sort the results instead. All you need to do is give the database something to sort by.

Add an `order` integer field to your model, and update those values when a user has created an order for your images; this is a simple numbering operation. Then when you query for the images for display, sort them on that field.

If images are shared between users, you'd need to make this a separate model; one that maps user to image with the order attached:

```
class ImageOrder(Model):
    """Keeps track ordering of images for a given user"""
    order = IntField()
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    image = ForeignKey(Image)
```

Now you can filter images by their relationship to a given user, and order them by the `order` field:

```
ImageOrder.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('order').select_related('image')
```

then use the `.image` field of each `ImageOrder` instance.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is the app heavily relies on displaying user images (in the order defined by them), in many different pages. Isn't the approach of doing a filtering based on 'order', and having the db to sort/filter images every time it needs to access them inefficient? I don't mind doing this approach, if there's no other easy way of manipulating the db, for the sake of efficiency.

Comment: @Rooz: databases are *highly optimised* to work with multiple tables. No, this isn't inefficient, relational database systems are all about combining things this way.